# I 'm getting some errors when seting up xampp

Tags: xampp

I'm getting that error when trying to set up site on localhost

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed:
>   No such host is known. ' in C:\xampp\htdocs\1\PHP Pro Bid
>   v7.6\library\Cube\Db\Adapter\PDO\Mysql.php:110 Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\1\PHP Pro Bid
>   v7.6\library\Cube\Db\Adapter\PDO\Mysql.php(110):
>   PDO->__construct('mysql:host=http...', 'ubidu_ge',
>   'AhJae!x5Gojetha...', Array) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\1\PHP Pro Bid
>   v7.6\library\Cube\Db\Adapter\PDO\Mysql.php(135):
>   Cube\Db\Adapter\PDO\Mysql->_connect() #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\1\PHP Pro Bid
>   v7.6\module\Install\src\Install\Model\Parser.php(375):
>   Cube\Db\Adapter\PDO\Mysql->canConnect() #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\1\PHP Pro
>   Bid v7.6\module\Install\src\Install\Controller\Index.php(230):
>   Install\Model\Parser->parse(true) #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\1\PHP Pro Bid
>   v7.6\library\Cube\Controller\Dispatcher.php(131):
>   Install\Controller\Index->Index() #5 C:\xampp\htdocs\1\PHP Pro Bid
>   v7.6\library\Cube\Controller\Front.php(411):
>   Cube\Controller\Dispatcher->dispatch(Object(Cube\Controlle in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\1\PHP Pro Bid
>   v7.6\library\Cube\Db\Adapter\PDO\Mysql.php on line 114

Comment: Don't you see the reason in that error message? No such host is known

Comment: so how to fix it ?

Comment: Change the host name on line 110 of C:\xampp\htdocs\1\PHP Pro Bid v7.6\library\Cube\Db\Adapter\PDO\Mysql.php

Comment: I think you should change to localhost

Comment: when I try to install it tells that I'm running MySQL 5.1 and recommended one is 5.5 and it fails that can be a reason ?

Comment: Ya it could be. Depending on your framework though.

Comment: It's cube framework